# Decimal point control

Tags: java

I doing a program that will print out the sum and average of a set of numbers. I'm pretty new to java, and I can't seem to figure out how to get the .7 that is supposed to be on the end of the average, I only get .0. I don't think it has to do with my math, I think there is an error in my rounding statement. Could someone point the error out to me? Thanks guys.

```
    public class Program
  {
            public static void main (String[]args)
            {
                int a = 475;
                int b = 821;
                int c = 369;
                int d = 562;
                int e = a+b+c+d;
                double f = e/4;
                f=(int)(f*10+.5)/10;
                System.out.println("The sum of the four numbers is "+ e + "       and the average is "+ f);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Take a look at my solution below.

Comment: Question (topic, thema) is totally wrong to the text

Comment: "Div of integers problem" etc Nobody here dont move decimal point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `double f = e/4;`, do `double f = e/4.0;`

With `e/4`, you divide an `int` by an `int`, which results in an `int`. The result is afterwards assigned to a `double`. That's why you don't get decimals in your result.

With `e/4.0`, you divide an `int` by a `double`, which results in a `double`.

Comment: if you want only int value just call  int f=e/4;

Answer (score 0):

You lost the decimal point because e/4 is an integer. try e/4F to indicate the expression as float number

```
double f = e/4F;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have an integer divide by another integer, this is call **integer division**. The output will the discard the decimal values.

**For example**:

```
double v1 = 5/2;  //Value of v1: 2.0 (0.5 discarded)
double v2 = 10/3; //Value of v2: 3.0 (0.333 discarded)
```

An integer division is happening in your codes at this line:

```
double f = e/4;
```

Hence, all the decimal values are discarded.

---

To retain the decimal value, you can simply do **one** the following (to indicate one of the operand is a decimal value, hence integer division will not occur):

```
double f = e/4.0;
double f = e/(double)4;
double f = e/4d;
```